# Unfathomable encoding behaviour of Eclipse connected to MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, unicode, encoding, odbc

First, I apologise for this question... yet another encoding issue I hear you say.

I have looked online generally and in the archives here for an answer to this.

I have Eclipse Indigo on a WXP OS.  My version of Access is old (Office 2000).

I have set up an JDBC:ODBC connection to the dbase which has French text and accents in it.

I get a simple ResultSet and both in the console and in the GUI, "?"s replace all accented characters.  I have tried setting every setting in sight to "UTF-8", including Eclipse's .ini file (-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8).

If I hard-code a string in the app code with French accented chars in it, these print fine both in the console and the GUI output.

So far so banal.  But what flummoxes me is when I run OUTSIDE eclipse (i.e. from a CMD window) the GUI components display the text perfectly, with all accents.  While any output to the CMD window is garbled, but in a different way from the Eclipse console (characters such as "Ú" replace all accented characters).

If only there were some sort of diagnostic flow chart about how to solve this sort of thing...

***edit***

connection line: (ragbag is name of database)...

```
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ragbag", "", "");
```

getting the RS:

```
   stmtEntries = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tblFrEng WHERE French LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'",
          ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet rs = stmtEntries.executeQuery();
```

getString and set GUI lines:

```
   String[] row = new String[]{rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3) };
   ((DefaultTableModel)terms_table.getModel()).addRow( row );
```

***edit2***

More "clues": the following statement and parameter lists all the records with "é" in one of the dbases on my system... but when I then go and look at the table in Worksheet view the "é"s appear as"Ã©" ... 
Although there are other records where "é" is shown as "é" in Worksheet view... but these latter records were NOT picked up by the Like statement.
Furthermore, the "wildcard" character which works is "%" although the wildcard used in Access is "*"... anyway.  All attempts to put this string inside the SELECT statement (i.e. no parameter) fail.

```
  PreparedStatement stmtEntries = c.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM tblNodes WHERE   Title LIKE ?", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
  stmtEntries.setString( 1, "%é%");
```

Comment: Show the code where you are making the Connection, particularly the query parameters in the JDBC URL.  Also show the call to ResultSet.getString and show the code that sets the string in the GUI.

Comment: Can you open the database in Access and verify that the text appears correctly when opening a table in Datasheet View? I just tested retrieving some accented characters from an Access 2000 database using a vanilla install of Eclipse (Android Developer Tools, actually) and the accented characters appeared correctly when I ran my Java program.

Comment: @Gord Yes, displays fine in Access datasheet view... there is no problem with displaying these chars in Access.  It's got to be (famous last words) be something to do with Eclipse configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I then go and look at the table in Worksheet view the "é"s appear as"Ã©" ... Although there are other records where "é" is shown as "é" in Worksheet view... but these latter records were NOT picked up by the Like statement

You apparently have some records in the database where the strings are encoded as single-byte ANSI characters (which appear as `é`) and other records where the strings are encoded as multi-byte Unicode characters (which appear as `Ã©`). You should expect to see inconsistent behaviour until you clean up your database so that all strings in `Text` and `Memo` columns are encoded the same way.

If I recall correctly, older version of Access expected text to be encoded as single-byte characters (probably the `Windows-1252` character set), while newer versions of Access expect strings to be encoded as multi-byte Unicode characters. If you plan to stay with the *very old* Access 2000 format you probably should standardize on single-byte character encoding.

You may also want to ensure that your default character encoding in Java matches the character encoding you use in your database. For more information on setting the default character encoding in Java, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3751791/2144390).

Comment: Thanks very much. Will follow your advice.

Comment: @GordThompson I just noticed you broke 10K.  Congratulations.  Feel the power!  :-)

Comment: @HansUp Thanks! I'll try not to let it go to my head. :)