# Can not use parenthesis in html which is defined in java

Tags: java, javascript, html

```
String mssg=mssg+"<ul onClick='getValue(this)'><li><click me</li></ul>";
```

I'm executing the java class which consist above code and retrieves the output in html page by using mssg variable.
But in html page the value of mssg comes like.....

```
 <ul onClick='getValue&x28;this&x29;'><li><click me</li></ul>
```

As we know the ascii value(hexa) of `'('` is `&#x28` but it comes something different.
So please help me to get the parenthesis instead of ascii code.
And why parenthesis is converted to that value, please explain.

Comment: Missing code in line 2: mssg=mssg+"<ul><li onclick='getvalue(this)'>click me</li></ul>";

Comment: Please elaborate are you trying to parse an html document?

Comment: So how are you converting the string into an HTML document? It looks to my like the string is being escaped when you don't want it to

Comment: 1) Use `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");` or 2) escape `"`: `String mssg=mssg+"<ul onClick=\"getValue(this)\"><li><click me</li></ul>";` or 3) change the encoding of your file... `Which IDE are you using?

Comment: no i'm not parsing document. i'm just inserting some html element to an html page @brso05

Comment: I'm just using html element as string and parsing that string to a html page  @Dragondraikk

Comment: @Jordi Castilla i m using eclipse java EE

Comment: So [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse)