# Highchart X-axis truncate shows weird characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having a problem with the truncation of the highcharts x-axis labels. In my website when the labels truncate it shows this weird characters in this image

[image: My website]

When I use the same exact code in JSFiddle it seems to work ok and instead of the weird characters it displays the `...` like it should

[image: JSFiddle]

Has anybody had the same problem? I'm using the same imports and the same jQuery version in JSFiddle.

I thought this may be a problem of encoding but I'm using UTF-8 for the encoding as in the JSFiddle.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Here is the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/6bm3p3cb/2/), I hope that somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your HTML file is also encoded in UTF-8. And try to use file directly from Highcharts CDN, not local files - maybe when saving file it was converted to CP1250 or something similar.

Comment: I have already tried that but the result was the same. I even set the tomcat encoding to UTF-8, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I still expect that generated HTML is not UTF-8. Try this: `xAxis: { categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.months } ` and let me know if you see the same issue.

Comment: Yes it still has the same issue :/

Comment: We have this same issue. Also, when we get the rendered page chart to use the ellipses the exported chart (using latest java+phantomJS build) still has the invalid characters. We solved it by modifying the highstock.js code to use '...' (3 periods) instead of the ellipses character.

Comment: I have the same issue, but my `highcharts.js` is already in UTF-8. The HTML, however says it is in ascii, but I guess is one of this "ascii is a subset of UTF-8" things, as I converted it to UTF-8 and it is still saying it is ascii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after all Paweł Fus was right on the first comment he made

> Make sure your HTML file is also encoded in UTF-8. And try to use file directly from Highcharts CDN, not local files - maybe when saving file it was converted to CP1250 or something similar.

The problem was solved by saving the highcharts libs as UTF-8.

To do that I had to change the encoding of eclipse like it's said here [How to change default text file encoding in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse) and then I saved the .js files.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `overflow:"justify"` for labels that are over flowing in your case.

Here is the reference:   http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bm3p3cb/3/)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. And besides that the overflow property is Deprecated and so it's not advised to use it