# Invalid character constant java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing a Converter app.
The following lines give me a syntax error called **Invalid character constant**.

I don't know how to deal with it.
Any kind of help or suggestion are welcome.

```
public static HashMap<Character, String> UNICODE_TRANS = new HashMap<Character, String>();
static {
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã·', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã—', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã·', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã—', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â²', "^2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â³', "^3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â�´', "^4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆ’', "-");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Âµ', "micro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ï€', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Î ', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â‚¬', "euro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â¥', "japanyen");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â‚¤', "greatbritainpound");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆš', "sqrt");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆ›', "cuberoot");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â½', "1|2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…“', "1|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…”', "2|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â¼', "1|4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…•', "1|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…–', "2|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…—', "3|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…™', "1|6");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…›', "1|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…œ', "3|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…�', "5|8");
}
```

Comment: `Ã·` sure looks like two characters to me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That works. But java will treat "Ã·" as String. so, how to convert that thing into character.

Comment: What do you when you ask how to convert a string to a character? The question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Which line in particular gives "Invalid character constant"? I guess it's the first, just supply that in the question

Comment: Side note. Don't use eclipse. Use android studio. Eclipse is legacy and unsupported now.

Comment: @MarounMaroun plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Comment: @weston plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Comment: @aioobe plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Frank N. Stein plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you have a lot of char constants that contain multiple characters. **A char constat must contain one and only one character**. That's why your code failed to compile.

You can solve this by deleting the extra characters. But in your comments, I think you implied that you want to keep the meaning of the constants. i.e. You don't want to change 'Ï€' to 'Ï' or '€' because it would lose its meaning.

**So for an alternative approach**, Use a `Map<String, String>` instead of a `Map<Character, String>`. This way, you are ale to store multiple characters!

Comment: plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This must be a character encoding issue. You opened an UTF-8 encoded file with ISO-latin-1 encoding. Change the *editor encoding* in Eclipse. [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse) how to do that.

For a *single file*, right-click the file, open `Properties`, and under `Resource` you can change Text File Encoding to `other` (and you can choose `UTF-8`).

Also, you might want to change the character encoding for the compiler, too. This can be done under Project Compiler settings. Right-click on the Project, choose Properties, you will see Builders or Compilers there. Then set the input file encoding.

Comment: plz. refer my answer. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change the editor settings? As far as I remember, you can open even single files with different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm giving the answer of my own question.
I've spoiled my half day because of **Eclipse IDE**. Eclipse doesn't open **UTF-8** file correctly.
When I opened the same file containing above code in simple **Notepad++** editor. It looks like following.

```
public static HashMap<Character, String> UNICODE_TRANS = new HashMap<Character, String>();
static {
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('÷', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('×', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('÷', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('×', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('²', "^2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('³', "^3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⁴', "^4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('−', "-");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('µ', "micro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('π', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('Π', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('€', "euro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('¥', "japanyen");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('₤', "greatbritainpound");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('√', "sqrt");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('∛', "cuberoot");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('½', "1|2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅓', "1|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅔', "2|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('¼', "1|4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅕', "1|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅖', "2|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅗', "3|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅙', "1|6");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅛', "1|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅜', "3|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('⅝', "5|8");
}
```

These will might help everyone who uses Eclipse IDE to keep these in Mind.

Here's the Eclipse Comptible Code

```
public static HashMap<Character, String> UNICODE_TRANS = new HashMap<Character, String>();
static {
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00F7', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00D7', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00F7', "/");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00D7', "*");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00B2', "^2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00B3', "^3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2074', "^4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2212', "-");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00B5', "micro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u03C0', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u03A0', "pi");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u20AC', "euro");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00A5', "japanyen");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00A3', "greatbritainpound");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u221A', "sqrt");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u221B', "cuberoot");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00BD', "1|2");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2153', "1|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2154', "2|3");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00BC', "1|4");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2155', "1|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2156', "2|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2157', "3|5");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u2159', "1|6");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u215B', "1|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u215C', "3|8");
    UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u215D', "5|8");
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is able to open UTF-8 files. It does help if you check the file encoding with other tools like Notepad++, but you can properly edit files in Eclipse after applying the character code setting.

Comment: Please go to Eclipse's `Preferences, General/Workspace/Text File Encoding` and set it to **UTF-8**

Comment: Another reason to use Android Studio and dump Eclipse.