# javac: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252 - selenide selector.by.text

Tags: java, selenium, encoding, ant, javac

I have a JUnit test, and need to run it using javac since I have a JunitTestSuite class that helps in running the tests in a specific order.

When I tried to execute the them using : javac command I got this error:

> unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
>   and this is a snapshot for error:

[image]

this point to this line from code:

```
        WebElement password_error = $(Selectors.byText("الاسم يجب أن يكون أكثر من 1 وأقل من 32 حرفا!"));
        $(password_error).shouldBe(visible);
```

Although it didn't give me any error for other Arabic strings which I got used such like following:

```
            $("div.alert.alert-danger").shouldBe(visible).shouldBe(text("تحذير : رقم الجوال مسجل مسبقا!"));
```

Comment: What is your java source encoding - UTF-8? Then compile with UTF-8.

Comment: how to know it from eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse

Comment: default encoding : Cp1252

Comment: Not much experience with Arabic, but I thought Cp1256 aka Windows-1256 was for Arabic. You could try UTF-8 in eclipse

Comment: Codepage windows-1252 is for Western European characters only. Use UTF-8 instead!

Comment: I change the default to UTF-8, but still the error appeared.
is there any change should we make? after changing then the change can affect these java classes.