# String thé is converted to "th??"

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding

I am using java 6 on linux machine in my application in am put "thé" into a text box but in my logs it print "th??", why this diacritic is converted to "th??" ?

the output I have seen on eclipse console, I am using eclipse Version: Kepler

There is simple program:-

```
String s="thé";
System.out.println(s);
```

OutPut:- "th??"

Comment: That Q is pretty broad, as you don't give information on (a) system locale (b) logger used (c) application environment for the unknown logger (d) version numbers of (a-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to be an encoding issue, check the encoding of your source file. You should be able to change it with your IDE.

To change encoding on eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
(Fetched from this post [How to change default text file encoding in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse))