# eclipse starting with wrong encoding

Tags: eclipse, fonts, character-encoding, gtk3

I just installed on a linux box gtk3, java jdk-10.0.2 and eclipse-java-2018-09-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz, and when I start it I see it like this.
Any idea what went wrong? 
Seems that all the characters are take from a wrong encoding!

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse

Comment: It's not only a file into eclipse, it's the whole eclipse interface that is not displayed correctly :(

Comment: actually was not only eclipse but many X applications were not working correctly. I have found that _yum groupinstall fonts_ solves my problem. see this [link](https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/x11-setup-gui-window-has-garbage-characters/kb000009221)

Answer (score 0):

actually was not only eclipse but many X applications that were not working correctly. I have found that 
yum groupinstall fonts 
solves my problem.

Simply the font needed was not there after installing only gtk3.